# Using GetProperties() with BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly in .NET Reflection

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

If I use

```
sometype.GetProperties();
```

I get all of the properties from the type and it's parent.  However I only want to retrieve the properties defined explicitly in this type (not the parents).  I thought that was what the `BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly` option was for.

However, when I try this:

```
sometype.GetProperties(BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
```

I get 0 properties.

Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `To all who come from google:` if you still can't get your "properties" even after setting flags, if you're new to c# and don't know the difference between `Properties` and `Fields`, try using `GetFields()`. You've probably been looking for `fields` all along!

Comment: @user1306322: just for the record, I "come from google" and my code is: `var types = type.GetFields.Select(f => f.FieldType).Union(type.GetProperties.Select(p => p.PropertyType));` - and  the results still count 0.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

If you specify any `BindingFlags`, then you need to specify explicitly what properties you want to get. For example:

```
sometype.GetProperties (BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | 
                        BindingFlags.Public | 
                        BindingFlags.Instance);
```

Answer (score 56):

To summarize:

1. if you use the [`GetProperties()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aky14axb%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) overload (without parameters), you will get all **public properties**.
2. on the other hand, if you use the [`GetProperties(BindingFlags)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyaxdd3x%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) overload (the one which accepts a `BindingFlags` parameter), then you need to specify a bitwise OR of at least one from each group of the following flags:

   - `BindingFlags.Instance` / `BindingFlags.Static` (instance vs static properties),
   - `BindingFlags.Public` / `BindingFlags.NonPublic` (public vs non-public properties).

For example, to get public static properties, you will need to call `GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)` in order to get results. Calling only `GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public)` or `GetProperties(BindingFlags.Static)` won't return any results.

Note also that specifying `BindingFlags.Default` will return an **empty array**.

Full details can be found in [MSDN documentation for GetProperties(BindingFlags)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyaxdd3x%28v=VS.90%29.aspx):

> The following BindingFlags **filter** flags can be used to define which nested types to include in the search:
>
> - You must specify either **`BindingFlags.Instance`** or **`BindingFlags.Static`** in order to get a return.
> - Specify **`BindingFlags.Public`** to include public properties in the search.
> - Specify **`BindingFlags.NonPublic`** to include non-public methods (that is, private, internal, and protected methods) in the search. Only protected and internal methods on base classes are returned; private methods on base classes are not returned.
> - Specify **`BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy`** to include public and protected static members up the hierarchy; private static members in inherited classes are not included.
>
> The following BindingFlags **modifier** flags can be used to change how the search works:
>
> - **`BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly`** to search only the properties declared on the Type, not properties that were simply inherited.

Comment: So to point this out: *without* any BindingFlags, there are some defaults. Do you know which they are?

Comment: If you use the `GetProperties()` overload (without parameters), you will get all public properties.

But `GetProperties(BindingFlags.Default)` will return an empty array.

Comment: Heh, so what's the use of BindingFlags.Default?! ;)

Comment: It's recommended that all enums marked with a Flags attribute have a defined enum value for `0`. Since the underlying type for the enums flags is int, you must have an enum which represents the default value of int. You are likely to get a 0 value when you are instantiating it or doing bitwise operations with the flags.

Comment: "then you need to specify a logical OR"  - you mean a bitwise OR ?

Comment: ➕1 for including the details of that arcane enum

Answer (score 21):

You need to expand your BindingsFlag a bit.  They need to at least include what accessibility level and instance vs. static in order to get anything meaningful back.

I think what you are actually looking for is the following

```
var flags = BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly 
  | BindingFlags.Instance
  | BindingFlags.Public;
someType.GetProperties(flags);
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags.aspx) site.

> Default (member) Specifies no binding flag.
>
> You must specify Instance or Static along with Public or NonPublic or
> no members will be returned.

Hence unless you specify the binding flags you get nothing.

Answer (score -1):

I had problems using `typeof(Thing)`, eventually this worked for me:

```
        var thisThing = (new Thing()).GetType();
        foreach (var property in thisThing.GetProperties())
        {
            // ...
        }
```