# Type.GetProperties returning nothing

Tags: c#, reflection, linker, xamarin.ios

Consider the following code:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(Type optionsClassType)
    {
      //A PropertyInfo[0] is returned here
      var test1 = optionsClassType.GetProperties();
      //Even using typeof
      var test2 = typeof(MyClassOptions).GetProperties();
     //Or BindingFlags
      var test3 = typeof(MyClassOptions)
          .GetProperties(BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Public);
    }
}

public class MyClassOptions
{
    public int MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

I'm unable to get `PropertyInfo[]` about `MyClassOptions`, [`Type.GetProperties`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getproperties.aspx) always returns an empty array. First I thought that was a framework bug in Xamarin.iOS, but I tested the same code in another project targeting the same framework and it worked just fine.

Anyone knows possible causes for this?

**EDIT**

Thanks to @Fabian Bigler answer I got it.
In my project, even with Linker set to a moderate behavior, instantiating `MyClassOptions` was not enough to keep the class definition at runtime. Only after actually using the instance(e.g. setting a property) the class is kept in my build.

Seems that linker replaces "unused" stuff with dummies.
Since I'll use reflection a lot in this project I've just disabled the Linker and everything is working again.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This code works perfectly fine for me:

```
namespace MyNameSpace
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        public MyClass(Type optionsClassType)
        {
            //A PropertyInfo[0] is returned here
            var test1 = optionsClassType.GetProperties();
            //Even using typeof
            var test2 = typeof(MyClassOptions).GetProperties();
            //Or BindingFlags
            var test3 = typeof(MyClassOptions).GetProperties
(BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
        }
    }

    public class MyClassOptions
    {
        public int MyProperty { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Added `BindingFlags.Instance` in code. For further information, have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544979/net-reflection-getproperties-with-bindingflags-declaredonly).

---

Then call this from outside:

```
var options = new MyClassOptions();
    options.MyProperty = 1234;
    var t = options.GetType();
    var c = new MyNameSpace.MyClass(t);
```

---

### NOTE: Be careful with assembly linker

If you're building with linker enabled you may need to use the class somewhere, so it will not be ripped off at compile time.  Sometimes, only instantiating the class in your code is not enough, the linker may detect that the instance is never used and will remove it anyway.

Comment: For some reason only the first two worked for me, using the binding flags returned an empty array (using visual studio 2010)

Comment: @Cemafor Check out my updated answer, you forgot to add 'BindingFlags.Instance'

Comment: In a clean project this code works for me too, but when I try to do this in my bigger project something went wrong and a empty array is returned... even after coding this example ad-hoc in this project. Something must be wrong with the project itself, sincerely I don't know.

Comment: @cvsguimaraes: Interesting. Is it the same target framework? AFAIK, there is nothing against this code running in a larger project.

Comment: @FabianBigler Yes I used the same framework. Maybe some project option?

Comment: @FabianBigler: I wouldn't say I forgot, I just copied the code as is (or as was) and was reporting what I saw :)

Comment: @Cemafor you are right, I'm sorry. I thought you were the PO. ;)

Comment: @cvsguimaraes I can only recommend you to doublecheck it again, since I can not reproduce it.

Comment: @FabianBigler I already got it mate. Checkout the edit in my question. Thanks!

Comment: @cvsguimaraes:same problem. Seems to be ok when created in empty project but doesn't work if I am trying to use it in the existing one

Comment: @MarkKarwowski See my edit at the end of this answer. Double check the projects configurations and framework versions...