# Get Properties of baseclass and specific inherited class

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a base class CrmObject and a few classes that inherit it (Aufgabe, Kontakt, ...). I only have a string-value for the child-class and I want to get both the Properties of CrmObject and the specific child-class in one Statement.

I'd get the properties of the child-class like this:

```
var propertyInfos = typeof(CrmObject).Assembly.GetType("Aufgabe").GetProperties().Where(p => Attribute.IsDefined(p, typeof(ImportParameter)));
```

But I'd like to get the Properties of CrmObject, too. Possibly within the same statement.

[UPDATE]
This should be it. I'll test it later. Thank you, guys. :)

```
var propertyInfos = typeof(CrmObject).Assembly.GetType("DAKCrmImport.Core." +crmType).G‌​etProperties().Where(p => Attribute.IsDefined(p, typeof(ImportParameter)));
```

Weirdly enough you don't need the bindingflag parameter to flatten the hierarchy. Apparently it's the default value? Well .. whatever. It works :)

Comment: You need `BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy`.

Comment: Your code should work fine. Try removing the where clause.

Comment: Ohh thank you. So the Statement would look like this:`var propertyInfos = typeof(DAKCrmImport.Core.Entities.CrmData.CrmObject).Assembly.GetType(crmType).GetProperties(BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy).Where(p => Attribute.IsDefined(p, typeof(ImportParameter)));`

Comment: GetType excpects the FullName of the type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works fine for me.

```
public class CrmObject
{
    [ImportParameter]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Aufgabe : CrmObject
{
    [ImportParameter]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class ImportParameterAttribute : Attribute
{

}

public class InheritenceProgram
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var propertyInfos = typeof(CrmObject).Assembly.GetType("Aufgabe").GetProperties().Where(p => Attribute.IsDefined(p, typeof(ImportParameterAttribute)));
        var list = propertyInfos.ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Uhm .. but I want the properties of CrmObject, too. I'm pretty sure I wouldn't get them this way. I'd only get the properties of "Aufgabe".

Comment: `GetType` excpects the `FullName` of the type.

Comment: You'll get all properties marked with the attribute ImportParameter. In my example you should get Id and Name.

Comment: And as Amit Kumar Ghosh commented, you need to use the FullName with GetType. My example only works if you don't use a namespace.

Answer (score 1):

As Mark said, you need to specify `BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy`.
But when you specify the `BindingFlags`, you need to specify exactly what you want. That means that you also have to specify `BindingFlags.Instance` to get the *instance members* and `BindingFlags.Public` to include *public members*.

So the command would look like this:

```
var propertyInfos = typeof(CrmObject).Assembly.GetType(crmType).G‌​etProperties(BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public).Where(p => Attribute.IsDefined(p, typeof(ImportParameter)));
```

You can read more about it in this [great SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1544992/3107430) and in the documentation of [Type.GetProperties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/kyaxdd3x%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).