# Exposing a Schema that is not exposed by default with Swagger

Tags: c#, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

Swagger exposes by default any schema that is used by an exposed controller (API end point). How can a schema (class) be exposed if it is *not* used by a controller?

For example, Swagger is showing the following Schemas:

[image: Swagger Schemas]

But, the Song Schema (below) needs to be exposed. It is not exposed because it is not used by a controller (API end point).

```
using System;
namespace ExampleNamespace
{
    public class Song
    {
        [Key][Required]
        public int SongID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string SongName { get; set; }
        public string SongDescription { get; set; }
        public int SongLength { get; set; } //seconds
        [Required]
        public int AlbumID { get; set; }
    }
}
```

How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a schema using a DocumentFilter

```
public class AddSongSchemaDocumentFilter : IDocumentFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiDocument swaggerDoc, DocumentFilterContext context)
    {
        var songSchema = new OpenApiSchema {...};
        songSchema.Properties.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, OpenApiSchema>("songName", new OpenApiSchema { ... }));
        ...

        context.SchemaRepository.Schemas.Add("Song", songSchema);
    }
}
```

The class [OpenApiSchema](https://github.com/microsoft/OpenAPI.NET/blob/vnext/src/Microsoft.OpenApi/Models/OpenApiSchema.cs) is used for the song schema itself, and for property schemas. This type contains a number of documentation related properties you can set such as `Description`.

You register `AddSongSchemaDocumentFilter`  like so

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
    {
        options.DocumentFilter<AddSongSchemaDocumentFilter>();
    });
}
```

This could be a bit tedious if there are many properties. Using reflection, you can iterate on the properties, and even reflect on associated attributes attached to those properties.

```
var songSchema = new OpenApiSchema() { };
var song = new Song();
var properties = typeof(Song).GetProperties();

foreach (var p in properties)
    songSchema.Properties.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, OpenApiSchema(
        p.Name,
        new OpenApiSchema()
        {
            Type = p.PropertyType.ToString(),
            Description = // get [Description] attribute from p,
            // ... etc. for other metadata such as an example if desired
        }));

context.SchemaRepository.Schemas.Add("Song", songSchema);
```

[Full Swashbuckle documentation](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/blob/master/README.md).

Comment: Great! I was able to add a Schema! Is there a way to add the Song class without specifying all of the properties individually (assuming that I want to expose all of the Properties on the Class)?

Comment: @CardiDeMonacoJrYou could use reflection to do this. Another way might be to document your `Song` class with standard .NET XML doc comments, and then direct Swashbuckle to load these types with `SwaggerGenOptions.IncludeXmlComments`. If those work, I can update the answer...

Comment: Adding standard .NET XML doc comments does not appear to load anything additional. I added, for example, the songName property on the song after adding the comments, and I do not see anything additional. Reflection would certainly be an interesting route. I may try that, as there will end up being hundreds of properties. If reflection works, I'll revisit this question and share my code. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Reflection is very slick :)

`var songSchema = new OpenApiSchema() { };`
`Song song = new Song();`
`PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(Song).GetProperties();`
`foreach (var p in properties)
     songSchema.Properties.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, OpenApiSchema>(p.Name, new OpenApiSchema() { Type = p.PropertyType.ToString() }));`
`context.SchemaRepository.Schemas.Add("Song", songSchema);`

Comment: @CardiDeMonacoJr sure thing! I wasn't sure if the XML route was additional. I think all "normal" schemas are determined based on the endpoint signatures and all types referenced from the types in these signatures. Would be nice if it was additive... perhaps a good feature request to make.

Comment: And apparently I have no clue how to properly format code in a comment... so anyone please feel free to edit my last comment if able...

Comment: @CardiDeMonacoJr I've included your comment inline. Note, you can make the schema definition richer by reflecting attributes that you add to `Song`'s properties such as [`Description("Name of the song")] string SongName { get; set; }`

Comment: And for GetProperties, for anyone else looking at this, use `GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly)` to not also grab the inherited properties. Or refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544979/using-getproperties-with-bindingflags-declaredonly-in-net-reflection).