# Removing some schemas/models from API-Platforms Swagger/OpenAPI documentation output

Tags: symfony, swagger, openapi, api-platform.com

API-Platform will generate Swagger/OpenAPI route documentation and then below documentation for the Schemas (AKA Models) (the [docs](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/openapi/#openapi-specification-support-formerly-swagger) show them as "Models" but current versions such as 2.7 show them as "Schemas").

Where is the content generated to show these schemas/models?  How can some be removed?  The functionality to display them is part of Swagger-UI, but API-Platform must be responsible for providing the JSON configuration and thus which to change API-Platform and not Swagger-UI. Note that [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67725942/1032531) shows how to add a schema but not how to remove one.  Is there any documentation on the subject other than [this](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/json-schema/) which doesn't go into detail?

As seen by the output below, I am exposing `AbstractOrganization`, however, this class is extended by a couple other classes and is not meant to be exposed, but only schemas for the concrete classes should be exposed.  Note that my `AbstractOrganization` entity class is not tagged with `@ApiResource` and is not shown in the Swagger/OpenAPI routing documentation but only the schema/model documentation.

Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty certain there are better ways to implement this, however, the following will work and might be helpful for others.

```php
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);
namespace App\OpenApi;

use ApiPlatform\Core\OpenApi\Factory\OpenApiFactoryInterface;
use ApiPlatform\Core\OpenApi\OpenApi;
use ApiPlatform\Core\OpenApi\Model\Paths;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface;

class OpenApiRouteHider implements OpenApiFactoryInterface {

    public function __construct(private OpenApiFactoryInterface $decorated, private TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage)
    {
    }

    public function __invoke(array $context = []): OpenApi 
    {
        $openApi = $this->decorated->__invoke($context);

        $removedPaths = $this->getRemovedPaths();

        $paths = new Paths;
        $pathArray = $openApi->getPaths()->getPaths();
        foreach($openApi->getPaths()->getPaths() as $path=>$pathItem) {
            if(!isset($removedPaths[$path])) {
                // No restrictions
                $paths->addPath($path, $pathItem);
            }
            elseif($removedPaths[$path]!=='*') {
                // Remove one or more operation
                foreach($removedPaths[$path] as $operation) {
                    $method = 'with'.ucFirst($operation);
                    $pathItem = $pathItem->$method(null);                    
                }
                $paths->addPath($path, $pathItem);
            }
            // else don't add this route to the documentation
        }
        $openApiTest = $openApi->withPaths($paths);

        return $openApi->withPaths($paths);
    }

    private function getRemovedPaths():array
    {
        // Use $user to determine which ones to remove.
        $user = $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();
        return [
            '/guids'=>'*',                  // Remove all operations
            '/guids/{guid}'=>'*',           // Remove all operations
            '/tenants'=>['post', 'get'],   // Remove only post and get operations
            '/tenants/{uuid}'=>['delete'], // Remove only delete operation
            '/chart_themes'=>'*',
            '/chart_themes/{id}'=>['put', 'delete', 'patch'],
        ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify via annotations parameters which schema to hide, example:

```
#[GetCollection(
    openapiContext: [
        'hide' => true,
    ],
)]
```